# Setting Status icon for CFAPI does not work as expected

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, minifilter

I try to set the status icon of the placeholder file created with CFAPI to error. (see below)

[image: screen with error icon]

content of folder T:
[image: screen with cloud symbol]

I set the error state on the file, but it does not display the error. However the error is displayed on the containing folder.

I use following code to set the error on the file (the complete code is published on [github](https://github.com/LokiMidgard/CloudTest/tree/error-Icons)):

```cpp
void SetTransferStatus(_In_ PCWSTR fullPath, _In_ SYNC_TRANSFER_STATUS status)
{
    // Tell the Shell so File Explorer can display the progress bar in its view
    try
    {
        // First, get the Volatile property store for the file. That's where the properties are maintained.
        winrt::com_ptr<IShellItem2> shellItem;
        winrt::check_hresult(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(fullPath, nullptr, __uuidof(shellItem), shellItem.put_void()));

        winrt::com_ptr<IPropertyStore> propStoreVolatile;
        winrt::check_hresult(
            shellItem->GetPropertyStore(
                GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS::GPS_READWRITE | GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS::GPS_VOLATILEPROPERTIESONLY,
                __uuidof(propStoreVolatile),
                propStoreVolatile.put_void()));

        // Set the sync transfer status accordingly
        PROPVARIANT transferStatus;
        winrt::check_hresult(
            InitPropVariantFromUInt32(
                status,
                &transferStatus));
        winrt::check_hresult(propStoreVolatile->SetValue(PKEY_SyncTransferStatus, transferStatus));

        // Without this, all your hard work is wasted.
        winrt::check_hresult(propStoreVolatile->Commit());

        // Broadcast a notification that something about the file has changed, so that apps
        // who subscribe (such as File Explorer) can update their UI to reflect the new progress
        SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, static_cast<LPCVOID>(fullPath), nullptr);

        //wprintf(L"Succesfully Set Transfer Progress on \"%s\" to %llu/%llu\n", fullPath, completed, total);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // winrt::to_hresult() will eat the exception if it is a result of winrt::check_hresult,
        // otherwise the exception will get rethrown and this method will crash out as it should
        wprintf(L"Failed to Set Transfer Progress on \"%s\" with %08x\n", fullPath, static_cast<HRESULT>(winrt::to_hresult()));
    }
}
```

In addition, if I delete the file and create a new file the state will still be on error.

Comment: Hi,I can reproduce this issue now. And I will confirm it with Internal engineer, and response here if there is any update.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why the status is set by the `IPropertyStore::SetValue` function. I think this is the cause of the problem. I think you can refer to the [official sample](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html) to achieve your needs.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT I'm interrested in that link, but it seems to be be broken :( The bottom of the page shows `Error:null|403`

Comment: Sorry, I caused the error. You can refer to: [CloudMirror](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror)

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT Thanks I based my project on the sample. However the setting of the error status is not in the sample. You can set additional icons, but not set the first icon to an error status. I think I havn't seen such code in the sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed me to an [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/pull/154) in the windows cloud mirror sample that shows how to accomplish this.

This is the code:

```cpp
void Utilities::UpdateErrorOnItem(PCWSTR path, bool setError)
{
    try
    {
        winrt::com_ptr<IShellItem2> item;
        winrt::check_hresult(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(path, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(item.put())));

        winrt::com_ptr<IPropertyStore> propertyStore;
        winrt::check_hresult(item->GetPropertyStore(GPS_READWRITE | GPS_EXTRINSICPROPERTIESONLY, IID_PPV_ARGS(propertyStore.put())));

        PROPVARIANT propVar{};
        if (setError)
        {
            propVar.vt = VT_UI4;
            propVar.ulVal = static_cast<unsigned long>(E_FAIL);
            winrt::check_hresult(propertyStore->SetValue(PKEY_LastSyncError, propVar));
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear by setting to empty
            propVar.vt = VT_EMPTY;
            winrt::check_hresult(propertyStore->SetValue(PKEY_LastSyncError, propVar));
        }

        winrt::check_hresult(propertyStore->Commit());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // winrt::to_hresult() will eat the exception if it is a result of winrt::check_hresult,
        // otherwise the exception will get rethrown and this method will crash out as it should
        wprintf(L"Failed to set error state with %08x\n", static_cast<HRESULT>(winrt::to_hresult()));
    }
```

Comment: Does it require calling "SHChangeNotify" after "propertyStore->Commit()"? I tried your code, but the 'status' column is not changed(The value of 'status' is 'Sync pending'). Thanks.

Comment: @MartinZ Sorry but Since I no longer working on this Project, and with Windows Apis in general I can't tell you. It is too long for me to remember and I no longer have access to the source code used in the product. So I can't look it up.